# What can developers see in my address book?

Tags: ios, contacts, privacy

When Facebook or other developers ask for access to your address book, what content can they see?

For example, is this only limited to names and email addresses and phone numbers or does this include *everything* including notes, anniversary dates, birthdays, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can access **everything** that's displayed in the Address book.

More about that can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/AddressBook.html).

Comment: Wow thanks Matthieu that is quite troubling to hear. I don't see anything so far that says you can specifically read the notes section but I trust by everything you mean everything. I can't mark your answer as an answer for several minutes but will do so later.

Comment: The question is what do they do with all the information, beside the promises not to make it public? What is the reason for them having access to my personal address book ?

Comment: I had the same question... Recently when Whatsapp asked for my address book, I hesitated and did not allow access. Moments later, 2 spam messages appeared in iMessage. I assume coincidence. However, when thinking of all the content of the address book, would it not make sense to have options of what developers are allowed to see. ie: Why would 'using' Whatsapp require them to know my birthdays. I can see how they might want to 'harvest' the information. But the harvesting of all info is quite troubling... Interested to know if others are concerned too. Surprised not to hear more about this...